# Upgrading JSON documents with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

We've got some JSON docúments already defined, that are used as a storage format in a document database and also that are sent over a service bus.

These deserialize into concrete classes using JSON.NET. I'd now like to modify an existing property to hold additional data (e.g. Currently one of my classes contains an array of strings, but now I'd like it to be an array of a class that contains a string plus a timestamp.)

I need to still be able to deserialize the old document format, however. Is there a way, perhaps with a custom `JsonConverter`, to seamlessly convert to the new document format when an old one comes in? On serialization, I'd want all documents to be saved in the new format.

Since I've been asked to add technical detail, here's a contrived example for discussion:

```
public class Document
{
    public string[] Array { get; set; }
}
```

This gets upgraded into:

```
public class Document
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public Entry[] Array { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, let's assume that any old format document that comes in should end up with a timestamp of `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: Though interesting, the question lacks technical details, such as the JSON structure (old and new)

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro That's because its a general purpose question. This has nothing to do with a particular JSON structure; I happen to have 4-5 document formats that need upgrading at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current example you can use [CustomCreationConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) for Entry class. Implementation of `CustomCreationConverter<Entry>`:

```
public class DocumentEntryCreationConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Document.Entry>
{
    public override Document.Entry Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Document.Entry();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // If this is not an object - looks like an old format
        // So we need only set a value
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String) 
        {
            Document.Entry entry = this.Create(objectType);
            entry.Value = reader.Value as string;
            return entry;
        }
        else
        {
            // This is new format, we can recognise it as an object
            Debug.Assert(
                reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject, 
                "reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject");
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how you can apply it for Entry class:

```
public class Document
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DocumentEntryCreationConverter))]
    public class Entry
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public Entry[] Array { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting concept.  With all this new NoSQL stuff, this looks like a cool way to handle a particular change, if you think of it ahead of time... would just need to somehow come up with a document "format" tag from the get-go so that as you have old docs from 3 changes ago, you could upgrade them seemlessly.

Comment: If I wanted to start tagging documents for version number, would I be able to do so on the root `Document` class (not the inner `Entry` class) and then get at that version number from in a converter that operates on `Entry`?

Comment: I don't know about how to get access to the root object from `CustomCreationConverter`. This is my suggestion for your case (a) Remove attribute `CustomCreationConverter` (b) Use `JsonTextReader` on a JSON string to read first JSON object, which will help you to find the version of response. For example `{ 'v' : 2, 'document' : { ...  } }`. (c) Read the `document` value as you usually do with `JsonConvert.Deserialize`, but with converters: `JsonConvert.Deserialize(jsonDocument, new DocumentEntryCreationConverter(version))`.

Comment: Doing that would mean putting a lot of non-domain logic into my actual application, to determine which converters to use.